# MPAndroidChart barchat get the selected category

Tags: java, android

Am using android mpchart and i have been able to get the x axis value of my chart but i have two bars one showing inspected and another showing failed

so i have managed to get the category name as per x axis via

```
        mChart.setOnChartValueSelectedListener(new OnChartValueSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onValueSelected(Entry e, Highlight h) {
            final String x = mChart.getXAxis().getValueFormatter().getFormattedValue(e.getX(), mChart.getXAxis());

            Log.i("test", "value string is "+x.toString()); //gives me the group category
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected() {

        }
    });
```

Now with the above log am gettting the correct group that is if it is  `lexus, monte, normal or pickers`
My chart is

[image]

NOw i would like to get if its a category a or b selected.
How do i go on about this to identify if its a or b selected

Comment: check this : https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/609
Using odd - even index you can identify what you want.

Comment: @Nik i see but how do i check if it is odd or even?

Comment: using dataSetIndex

Comment: @Nik I see now using dataSetIndex i can get an integer value which is 1 or 0 then get if its a or b Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check this : github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/issues/609 Using odd - even index you can identify what you want.